# Are all elementary matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since elementary matrices are one step away from the identity matrix, does that mean all of them are diagonalizable?

Comment: They are not “diagonalizable” in the usual sense of the word. For instance $\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$ fails to be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$. This is an elementary matrix. But since it is Jordan and not diagonal it can't be diagonalizable.